# Oversampling with Cross Validation in PySpark Pipeline

Tags: python, pyspark, cross-validation, oversampling, smote

I'm working on a PySpark binary classification Pipeline where I want to perform CrossValidation with an Oversampling stage (My dataset is not balanced). The issue is that the oversampling stage is executed also on the test dataset.

The pipeline:

```
pipeline=Pipeline(stages=[cast_and_fill_na, smote, vec_assembler, rf])
```

`smote` is the stage I want to skip when transforming the test dataset.

I took a look in spark documentation and source code, There's no way to skip a stage in a PipelineModel. My solution was to override `_transform` methode of the original class in order to skip the ovesampling stage. 
This works fine when fiting the pipeline in my source code. I use this:

```
pipeline_model.__class__ = CustomPipelineModel
```

`CustomPipelineModel` is a class that inherits from `pyspark.ml.PipelineModel` and overrides the `_transform` method.

But as the CrossValidator uses the original implementation of the PipelineModel class, I can't use my custom method.

```
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(labelCol=target)    
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline,
                                      estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                                      evaluator=evaluator,
                                      numFolds=10,
                                      parallelism=1)
cvModel = crossval.fit(train_set)
```

What is the best way to skip the oversampling stage when using Cross Validator ?

I started to look into the source code of the `_fit` method of `pyspark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator` thinking about overriding it too ... The second solution is to perform oversampling on the training dataset but this will introduce bias into the models in the cross validation process.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a work around for this problem.
In my SMOTEOversmapler class (smote stage is an instance of it), I added a atteribute namede `skip_transform` which is set to None when instancing a SMOTEOversmapler object. In the `_transform` method, I set this attribute to True. The next call to `_transform` (which is in the test phase) will be skipped. Here is a code snippet.

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    self.skip_transfrom = None
def _transform(self, df):
    if self.skip_transform:
         retrun df
    else:
         #Execute oversampling
         self.skip_transform = True
```